# Set position of the y axis to the right side with Chart js

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, line, axis, react-chartjs-2

Im working with chartjs ^4.3.2 and react-chartjs-2 currently generating a Line chart. I need to set the y axis to position right (right side of the chart, because it is initialy on the left side). I cant found nothing about it in the docs. And all i have for answers on stack overflow is working only for old version of this library.
May someone help me please ?